# How would I limit scope to the clicked element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple AngularJS app that I'd like to use to filter search results by tag. For a first step I'm  creating a list of filter links with which to toggle visibility of individual tags. The problem is that **a click on one link toggles the state of all links in the list**.

I realize that this may need to be refactored for my ultimate goal, but I'd like to learn what's happening here first. How can I limit scope to the clicked element?

The HTML:

```
<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="toggleSelected()">
        <span class="glyphicon" 
          ng-class="{'glyphicon-check': selected, 'glyphicon-unchecked': !selected}">
        </span> Office Productivity
    </a></li>

    <li><a href="" ng-click="toggleSelected()">
        <span class="glyphicon" 
          ng-class="{'glyphicon-check': selected, 'glyphicon-unchecked': !selected}">
        </span> Leadership
    </a></li>

    ...
</ul>
```

The JavaScript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

    // toggle the selected state of an element scope, with a default of true
    $scope.toggleSelected = function () {
        $scope.selected = $scope.selected ? !$scope.selected : true;
        return $scope.selected;
    };
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/otprj3du/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I refactored your code a bit, getting the checklist from the controller instead. Then I looped through the objects and in `ng-click` I called `toggleSelected` with an attribute (the title of the checkbox).

Here is the edited jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/otprj3du/3/

I added this into the scope:

```
$scope.checkBoxes = {
    'Office Productivity':0,
    'Leadership':0,
    'Communication Skills':0,
    'HR & Compliance':0,
    'Career Readiness':0,    
};
```

And rendered the list like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="(title,selected) in checkBoxes">
    <a href="" ng-click="toggleSelected(title)">
        <span class="glyphicon" 
          ng-class="{'glyphicon-check': selected, 'glyphicon-unchecked': !selected}">
        </span> 
        {{ title }}
    </a>
</li>
```

And in toggleSelected I simply edited `$scope.checkBoxes`:

```
$scope.toggleSelected = function (title) {
  $scope.checkBoxes[title] = $scope.checkBoxes[title] ? !$scope.checkBoxes[title] : 1;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to ponder a bit whether I can put `checkBoxes` in an object like that. What I've shown is a small sample of a potentially dynamic list, so I suspect it'll work out just fine. I'm heading out the door and will respond further in the morning.